# How to increase the dimension and improve the quality of a image in python?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I'm using a code that crops entities from a entity schema and extracts the text from each entity. But my problem is when I try to get the text, with tesseract, from each cropped entity in some cases the image is very small and I can't get the text.

For example from this schema:

[image]

I get this image:

[image]

But the text I get from this image is the next:

```
m_..1 vmcmarzsiv
m_.m.n wacmarassv
um,-man vARcHAR($57
Ingram uacmarzsv
m_m-crmm vmcmarzsﬁv
i:Ix_v|§7ln uacmaxznv

i:Ix_w:nnr mewnzm
m_.=u:-g mm 0
um,-mam rmsn us
my vmcmarzsiv

» m_..m. msmuurrzxr
m_.=s wacmarassv
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How are we expected to help without any code or data? As it stands this is both too vague and too broad.

Comment: You do know that mysqlworkbench will spit those diagrams out into sql right? If you click Database -> Forward Engineer it will import that schema into a database. If you click File -> Export there's a range of options including SQL.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with small image crops is to **upsample** them with different interpolation techniques from [*cv2.resize()*](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d) function using techniques such as **cv2.INTER_CUBIC** or **cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4**. 
[This link](https://chadrick-kwag.net/cv2-resize-interpolation-methods/) provides example upscaling results with different interpolation flags. 
Visit [this link](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121) for a complete list of *InterpolationFlags*.

Sample Code for *bi-cubic* interpolation:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("image.png")
upscaled_img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

And below's the output from Tessaract OCR with the upscaled_img:

```
? ink_id BIGINT(20)
> link_ufd VARCHAR(255)
> link_name VARCHAR(255)
> link_image VARCHAR(255)
> link_target VARCHAR(25)
> link_description VARCHAR(255)
> link_visible VARCHAR(20)
> link_owner BIGINT(20)
> link_rating INT(11)
> link_updated DATE TIME
> link_rel VARCHAR(255)
2 link_notes MEDIUMTEXT
> link_rss VARCHAR(255)
eee
```

Comment: have this error: upscaled_img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'

Comment: i solve it, but when i resize the image i don get a correctly extraction of the text.